# How should I approach making a custom form involving different model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model, routes

I'm rather new to Ruby, so I need guidance as how to approach this. I know how to make very simple forms, but I'm thinking of implementing a custom form that can generate a payroll for a business during a specific start and end date. I already have business and payroll models, but I'm not sure how to implement this type of custom form and properly route it to get it be fully functional. Are there any resources or pieces of guidance I can get to help me with this?

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to edit/save instances of both models when submitting one form?

Answer (score 0):

please checkout this link :[create an application on RoR](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Please go to the link above and get started by creating your very own application. I have started with this and have learned a lot from this. This will get you kick started on RoR. But I believe you need more guidance in Ruby also. So I am attaching some more useful links. Please check them out also.

1. [tutorails point - ruby](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/index.htm)
2. [ruby-lang documentation](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/)
3. [ruby guides](https://www.rubyguides.com/ruby-tutorial/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really get your issue... If your models Business and Payroll are linked (with :belongs_to and :has_many) you should check the [fields_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) method. You can nest it in a form_for/form_with to create fields associated to an other model. For instance you can do something like that:

```
#in your view

<%= form_with model: @business |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Something:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :something %>
  <%= f.fields_for @business.payroll do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.label "Something else:" %>
    <%= ff.text_field :something_else %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#in your controller

if @business.create(business_params)
  #...
end

if @business.payroll.create(payroll_params)
  #...
end
```

Hope it will help you !